# How do comparisons add to our time complexity?

Tags: time

Forgive me if this is a repeated question, but I am just learning C programming (after being relatively fluent in Python) and I began to think about time complexities.

I've [read elsewhere](http://www.quora.com/Why-not-ternary-instead-of-binary-or-even-balanced-ternary) that the reason we do not use ternary trees or n-ary trees is because many times they either

- reduce to binary,
- or take even longer, since the time complexity gained from the additional comparisons makes it unwieldy.

My question: how much "time" do we gain by performing the basic comparisons on a system, such as comparing the variables

> x == y,

or even more complicated comparisons? I might be able to look at two variables for myself, such as if x = 20 and y = 10, and know after a brief instance that they are of course not equal to one another. What about a computer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Maybe you're mixing some concepts. If you're talking about [Time Complexity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) or how it works in C programming language.

Comment: @emartinelli If you can explain how comparisons work in C, that would suffice. I admit my question might be a bit vague, and that is my fault. I guess I just don't know enough to be more specific.